# Add a new primary to a replicaset

Tags: mongodb

so I have a 3 node setup of mongodb replica set, but the data is older than the production database. So my initial idea to make every node existing on the replica set priority 0.5 and add the production DB to the replicaset with priority 1 so he will become the new primary and the secondary will sync with production and then I can unplug the production database again.

My question is I never done it, idk if it will work.

is better to just make a dump of production and restore it on primary node?

Comment: What do you mean by "the data is older than the production database"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "add the production DB to the Replica set"?

Comment: the replica set has data from an old dump from the production database like 1 week behind

Comment: the replica set has 3 nodes, I was thinking to add production database as another node to the replicaset, but with the priority 1 to it become a primary

Comment: Will not work. When you add a new node to your replica set then it will immediately run an initial sync, I. E. It gets the data from the "old" replica set

Answer (score 1):

You can add HIDDEN member to your production replicaSet and it will sync to the production without the application to know about it , later when it fully init sync you can stop it and reconfigure as standalone replicaSet PRIMARY and you can sync the other 2x members from your testing environment  so you will have the production data refreshed in your test replicaSet. (  if this is what you need. )